# How to Concatenate an Index in a String to Another String in Python

Tags: python, string, string-concatenation

I have a string of length for example 20

I want to go in a loop to concatenate a the last 6 characters in the string

I'm doing it like this:

```
leng = len(theString)

leng2 = leng -6

for i in range(leng2, leng)

      a += theString.index(i)

print a
```

But i'm getting an error in " a += theString.index(i) "

stating "TypeError: expected a character buffer object"

Comment: what you want to concatenate to last 6 character ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two string **A** and **B**. You want to concatenate last `6` character of `B` to `A`. If I am right, then you can do this:

```
# this is faster way
>>> A = "abcdefg"
>>> B = "0123456789"
>>> A = A + B[-6:]
>>> A
'abcdefg456789'
```

If you want to iterate through your string `B` to concatenate, then

```
>>> l = len(B)-6;
>>> for i in range(l,len(B)):
        A = A + B[i]
>>> A
'abcdefg456789'
```

Comment: Thx, The first method is exactly what I wanted and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

To get the character of a string `a` at index `i` you want to do `a[i]`. However, if I'm understanding the problem correctly, there is an easier way to do what you want.

You can [slice](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) the last 6 characters of a string, `a` like so:

```
a[-6:]
```

This will give you a 6-character string (assuming `a` has that many characters.)

So to concatenate the last 6 characters of a string to itself, you can do

```
a += a[-6:]
```

i.e, you don't need to do this character by character.

Answer (score 1):

`index` method of the string take substring from the string as a argument.
In code you given integer value that why such exception get.

update your code:

```
>>> for i in range(leng2, leng):
...    a += theString[i]
```

You can directly get last six character by `slice` method of the string.

```
>>> theString = "qazxswedcvfrtgbnhyuj"
>>> theString[-6:]
'bnhyuj'
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `theString.index` must be a string, so, use

```
a += theString.index(str(i))
```

However, your code must be incomplete -- for example, `a` is never initialized! -- so this fix, while indispensable, won't be sufficient.  Please show **all** the code and an example of what result you would expect for a certain initial value of `theString`.